# Simple PHP script to output mySQL database as XML

Tags: php, mysql

I'm taking a beginner class in PHP and I am trying to output a mySQL database as XML to a webpage.
Database name is `fruits` and it has three columns: `id`, `fruitname` and `fruitcolor`.

This is what I have in my code but it's not outputting anything. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
require_once "inc/db_connect.php";

if($db){
    echo "<p>Connected to Database Successfully</p>";
} elseif(isset($error)){
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}

?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, fruitname , fruitcolor from fruits";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('fruits');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $xml->startElement("id");

    $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);
    $xml->writeRaw($row['fruitname']);
    $xml->writeRaw($row['fruitcolor']);

    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();

?>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial to XMLWriter out, then you will see it yourself: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10356853-A-quick-PHP-XMLWriter-Class-Tutorial-%28XML-amp-RSS%29

Comment: What PHP error are you getting?

Comment: there should be a more simpler way to do this than what I am doing here.

Comment: Im not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because `$xml->openURI("php://output");` needs to be `$xml->openURI("php://stdout");`

If not try my other solution:

Have a look at [XMLWriter::flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-flush.php)

> If you opened the writer in memory, this function returns the generated XML buffer, Else, if using URI, this function will write the buffer and return the number of written bytes

Try exchanging `$xml->openURI("php://output");` with `$xml->openMemory();` and `$xml->flush();` with `echo $xml->flush();`

Resulting Code:

```
<?php
require_once "inc/db_connect.php";

if($db){
    echo "<p>Connected to Database Successfully</p>";
} elseif(isset($error)){
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}

?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, fruitname , fruitcolor from fruits";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('fruits');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $xml->startElement("id");

    $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);
    $xml->writeRaw($row['fruitname']);
    $xml->writeRaw($row['fruitcolor']);

    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->flush();

?>
```

Comment: this is what it ouputs now:                             <p>Connected to Database Successfully</p>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fruits/>

Comment: It seems that PHP isn't going into the While-Loop. Two reasons are possible. There are no entries in the Table fruits or there is an error in your SQL.

Comment: Its not the database as there are entries, so it must be the SQL. Is there a easier way to do this by using xml_decode():

Comment: To Check if there is an SQL-Error simply add this code after your `$res = mysql_qeuery($sql);` if(!$res) { echo mysql_error(); }

Comment: It successfully connect to the database